# Appium Pagefactory throws noSuchMethodException when running from POM

Tags: automated-testing, appium, page-factory, android-automation, pom

When I try to run my appium scripts on the pom file ( with mvn verify or mvn test)

I get a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy12.proxyClassLookup()
```

On the line that instantiates my locators:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15)), this);
```

When I run the test directly from InteliJ or run the testng.xml file, the test succeeds

- Full pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/V0FbehMh
- Full error stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/11TvTq7a
- testng.xml: https://pastebin.com/8XZtCfRt
- Related classes: https://pastebin.com/ynFizC9T

What can be the problem, when everything is fine running from test class / testng.xml, but suddenly failing when running with maven in command line

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit embarrassing, (because i remembered I did this before)
After doing an mvn clean, and an mvn compile again,

Then the issue disappeared. something probably got stuck somewhere and needed a clean again..